# how do I get a post to multi-site of wordpress in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I wanna post to multi-site of word-press in php
this code can make it but only to a main-wordpress below
this is not possible for multi-site
so I need to make it post to other multi-site
who can teach me how I can make and change code in php?
or I have to edit other files like wp-load.php or wp-config.php?

function autoPost($title, $desc) {

```
require_once("/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-load.php");
/*******************************************************
** explanation
*******************************************************/
$postType = 'post'; // post or page
$userID = 2; // user setting
$categoryID = '2'; // categoty number
$postStatus = 'publish'; 
$leadTitle = $title;
$leadContent = $desc;
$timeStamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+9 hour"));

$new_post = array(
'post_title' => $leadTitle,
'post_content' => $leadContent,
'post_status' => $postStatus,
'post_date' => $timeStamp,
'post_author' => $userID,
'post_type' => $postType,
'post_category' => array($categoryID)
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

$finaltext = '';
if($post_id){
    $finaltext .= 'successful<br>';
} else{
    $finaltext .= 'fail!<br>';
}
echo $finaltext;
```